# Xamarin Forms - Translating drawer menu items at runtime

Tags: c#, android, ios, xamarin, translate

I'm following the exelent tutorial ([Link](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/mastering-multilingual-in-xamarin-forms/)) on Multilingual in Xamarin.Forms

Everything is working well but I have one issue.

In my application I'm using Navigation drawer by Syncfusion as I'm generating the menu Items in a ListView as seen below.

DrawerPage.xaml

```
<ListView x:Name="listView"
                  SelectionMode="Single"
                  RowHeight="70"
                  ItemSelected="listView_ItemSelected"
                  SeparatorColor="Transparent">

                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ViewCell>
                            <StackLayout Margin="32,10,0,0" 
                                         VerticalOptions="Center" >

                                <Grid RowDefinitions="1*, Auto">

                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="50"/>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                                    <Label Grid.Row="0"
                                           Grid.Column="0" 
                                           HorizontalTextAlignment="Start"
                                           HorizontalOptions="Start"
                                           FontSize="25"
                                           FontFamily="Material-Outlined"
                                           Style="{StaticResource IconLabelStyle}"
                                           Text="{Binding Icon}" />

                                    <Label Grid.Row="0"
                                           Grid.Column="1"
                                           HorizontalTextAlignment="Start"
                                           HorizontalOptions="Start"
                                           Margin="10,0,0,0" 
                                           Text="{Binding Name}" 
                                           FontSize="16"/>

                                </Grid>
                            </StackLayout>
                        </ViewCell>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
```

DrawerPage.cs

```
private static string MAP = Lang.ResourceManager.GetString("Map");
private static string MAPICON = IconFont.ResourceManager.GetString("LocationOn");
private static string SETTINGS = Lang.ResourceManager.GetString("Settings");
private static string SETTINGSICON = IconFont.ResourceManager.GetString("Settings");

public partial class DrawerPage : ContentPage {
    drawerNavItems();
}

private void drawerNavItems()
{
    List<MenuItem> itemList = new List<MenuItem>();
    itemList.Add(new MenuItem { Icon = MAPICON, Name = MAP });
    itemList.Add(new MenuItem { Icon = SETTINGSICON, Name = SETTINGS });
    listView.ItemsSource = itemList;
 }
```

The issue I'm having is that I don't understand how I'm supposed to use the helper class in the tutorial link above to translate the drawer menu items.

In Xaml we can just translate the strings like this

```
Text="{helpers:Translate Support}"
```

But how do I do the same in the code Behind ?

Comment: isn't that what `Lang.ResourceManager.GetString` is doing?

Comment: It is not working at runtime

Comment: this is specifically addressed in the tutorial you linked to - https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/mastering-multilingual-in-xamarin-forms/#localized-c-text

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: the section I linked **directly** to - "Localized C# Text" - shows how to do exactly what you are asking

Comment: I have tried that - It is not working

Comment: "It's not working" is not a helpful description of the problem.  Please describe the specific behavior that it is or is not doing.

Comment: Give a minute - I will try to explaine

Comment: when setting the feild like this - `private string MAP = Lang.Map;` and then calling it in the listview - `itemList.Add(new MenuItem { Icon = MAPICON, Name = MAP });` - is giving it a hardcoded value that won't change at runtime

Comment: you are assigning static strings, so of course they will not change dynamically.  You can create bindings in code to match what is done in XAML

Comment: I know that - I'm asking for help on how to fix this properly